# rspec model testing in rails: method works but test wont pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have two models Indicator belongs_to Privacy.

In indicator I wrote a method to return the proper name of the privacy setting

```
def privacy
    Privacy.find(privacy_tag_id).content
end
```

That works in rails console.  If I create an Indicator and then run Indicator.privacy I get back "red" or "green" or whatever.  But I can't get my rspec to pass.  Here is the test

```
describe "indicator" do
    it "should return a human named when asked for its privacy level" do
        @privacy = PrivacyTag.create(:content => "Secret")
        @ind = Indicator.new(:content => 'test',
                             :privacy_tag_id => @privacy.id)
        @ind.privacy.should == "Secret"
    end
end
```

When I run the test I get this message:

```
Failures:

  1) indicator should return a human named when asked for its privacy level
     Failure/Error: @ind.privacy.should_equal "Secret"
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find PrivacyTag without an ID
     # ./app/models/indicator.rb:13:in `privacy'
     # ./spec/models/indicator_model_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong in my test?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that the `Privacy` object isn't being created. Try calling `create!` instead of `create`. If it raises an exception, then that means that your `Privacy` model has some validations in it.

It would've been super helpful to have seen your models in the first place.

Comment: Good call on the validation.  That was exactly the problem.  Sorry about not including the models.